# Преобразование типов С++

Tags: visual-c++, c++

Здравствуйте! Помогите в таком вопросе.
Как можно поместить в одном сообщении и путь искомого файла и размер блока, чтобы на сервере разъединить это в 2 переменные?
путь искомого файла и размер болка считываются из texbox2  и  textbox3

```
// А это отпрвка этого сообщения на сервер
send(my_socket, buff, (n-1), 0);
```

Comment: А напрямую в функцию передать str не получается?

Comment: А какая ошибка? В чём собственно вопрос, что конкретно не выходит?

Comment: Поддерживаю, @mikillskegg, правда, что мешает?

на сервере:

 std::vector< char >Buffer;
 SIZE_T len;
//
 len = strlen( msg );
 Buffer.resize( sizeof( SIZE_T ) + len );
 ::mmemove( &Buffer.at( sizeof( SIZE_T ) ), msg, len );
 *(SIZE_T*)&Buffer.front() = block_size;
 send(my_socket, &*Buffer.begin(), sizeof( SIZE_T ) + len, 0);

на клиенте:

 block_size = *(SIZE_T*)pRecvBuffer
 sprintf( MsgBuffer, "%.*s", int( RecvSize - sizeof( SIZE_T ) ), ((SIZE_T*)pRecvBuffer) + 1 );

Но раз это уже пакет, следовательно нужно следить, чтобы его размер был не меньше `sizeof( SIZE_T )`.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
std::string addr = marshal_as<std::string>(textBox2->Text);
send(my_socket, addr.c_str(), addr.length(), 0);
```

А вообще-то, держать в одном файле (не говоря уже о том, что в одном методе) код управления UI и сетевые операции -- не комильфо. Поделите всё на 2, а лучше -- 3 уровня: UI, отвечающий за текстбоксы и всё такое (это обычно называется View, UI Layer или Presentation); сетевые операции, отвечающие за сокеты и всё вокруг них (это у вас Model); ну и логику программы, которая эти две части связывает вместе и заставляет работать (называется громким именем Business Logic). Хорошо?

Comment: @VladD, а зачем нужна промежуточная std::string?

Comment: @avp: для автоочистки памяти. если бы был `char*`, простым delete его освободить нельзя -- память выделяется фиг знает где, не обязательно на heap. Вот тут немного подробностей: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19579/Using-and-extending-the-Orcas-marshal_as-library

Comment: @VladD, а для чего ее вообще тут чистить? Я совсем плохо знаком с M$, но IMHO должен быть способ получить адрес начала массива символов в textBox2->Text. 

Наверное какой-то [marshal_context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb384865.aspx) надо использовать для этого.

Comment: @avp: не всё так просто! Объекты в .net имеют право перемещаться в памяти. Например, сборка мусора часто сопровождается уплотнением памяти, то есть перемещением объектов. Так что надо либо pin'ить, либо копировать. Тем более, layout строк в .NET другой: допускаются встроенные нули.

Comment: @avp: marshal_context именно для того и нужен, чтобы освободить память. Я его не применял, потому что код выходит сложнее.

Comment: напрямую str передала..все нормально, теперь другой вопрос, как можно поместить в одном сообщении и путь искомого файла и размер блока, чтобы на сервере разъединить это в 2 переменные?

Comment: @Анна: ну придумайте свой формат. например, склейте в одну строку через какой-нибудь символ, например, ':'. Будет что-то типа "2000:c:\windows\system\virus.dll". На сервере надо будет найти первое двоеточие и по нему разрезать.

Answer (score 2):

Google buffers, boost serialize, xml, json вариантов много на самом деле.
То есть по сути вам надо просто придумаьт как хранить вашу структуру из двух полей в строке (как самое простое) и просто передавать/принимать эту строку по сети. Ну и парсер/распарсер написать для этого.

Client:

```
std::string sFileName = "...";
int nBlockSize = ...;
std::stringstream output;
output << sFilename <<" "<<nBlockSize;
std::string sToSend = output.str();
send(my_socket, sToSend.c_str(), sToSend.size(), 0);
```

Server:

```
std::string sReceived(buffer,received_len); //buffer содержит то что мы прочитали из соккета. received_len - сколько прочитали из сокета).
std::stringstream input(sReceive);
std::string sFileName;
int nBlockSize = 0;
input >> sFileName;
input >> nBlockSize;
```

Как-то так. Я сейчас очень приблизительно пишу, но смысл примерно ясен я надеюсь.

Comment: Очень много слов вместо одного sprintf() у клиента (кстати, сразу получаем размер отсылаемых данных) и sscanf() у сервера.

На самом деле, конечно же, надо учесть, что в имени файла **могут быть пробелы**. 

Формат можно сделать видимо такой:

    размер-блока имя-файла-заканчивающееся-нулем

Запись останется прежней, для чтения в сервере вызываем strtol(), а затем strcpy() в переменную для имени файла, хотя можно и сразу fopen() из буфера, на 1 байт после конца strtol().

--

И еще одно. Один recv() у сервера в "плохой" сети может не сработать... 

(как всегда места в комментарии мало)

Comment: 1) Формат это детали. Коротко: sprintf небезопасен. ну а более подробно про sprintf vs snprintf vs strstream vs stringstream можно прочитать у Саттера в Exceptional C++ Style (кажется задачи 2 и 3, сейчас под рукой нет).
1а) Как хорошо что в С++ есть потоки и не надо использовать всякие strtol и прочие strcpy. Жизнь сразу кажется легче ;)
2) Про то что recv должен быть в цикле это понятно. Тут дело даже не в плохой или хорошей сети. Но я намеренно оставил это за скобками.

Comment: @Andrey Buran, 

1) в данном случае формат (порядок имени файла и размера блока) это не детали, а способ уменьшить сложность программы, читающей имя файла с пробелами и т.п. символами.

2) Потоки в память на Си тоже есть (open_memstream() и т.п.), но в данном случае это не упрощает программу.

3) snprintf vs sprintf - на самом деле snprintf **не спасает**, реально всегда надо проверять согласованность входных данных и размеры буферов. Поясню: c snprintf ошибка просто "загоняется вглубь", программа не падает, а в целом комплекс не работает. Что лучше? *Бооольшой вопрос.*

(опять места мало...)

Comment: 1)Главное соблюсти баланс между сложностью программы и сложностью восприятия её программистом. Но принципиально конечно я не возражаю.
2)Ну мы тут всё-таки о плюсах говорим, если не ошибаюсь. Да и использовать эти потоки сишные ещё сложнее чем всякие strtol`ы
3)Да, и как раз об этом можно прочитать в указанных главах упомянутой мной книги. Там всё очень подробно разбирается. Рекомендую (всем, не только вам).

Comment: @Andrey Buran, 

1) главное в этом деле KISS-принцип (надо только не забывать - *но не проще, чем необходимо*).

2) и все таки, если C++ компилятор компилирует - то программа крестовая?

3) не знаком. А что (из программ) Саттер написал?

Comment: 1)Да
2)В С++ умышленно оставлена полная (уже не совсем, но раньше 100% ная) совместимость с C. И основной задачей Страуструп всегда ставил, чтобы любые задачи в С++ не требовали доп расходов по сравнению с C. Этот удачный "маркетинг" позволил плюсам завоевать популярность.Но это не значит что надо пользоваться "дедовскими" методами чтобы "прострелить себе ногу".
3)Архитектор в Microsoft С++/CLI, .NET и C# например. Секретарь комитета по стандарту С++. Ну вообще у него множество заслуг. Чего стоит один только gotw.com и comp.lang.C++.moderated . Ну можно в Википедии почитать ;) (см Herb Sutter